# Chefspec with Hashicorp Vault

Tags: chef-infra, hashicorp-vault, chefspec

I'm trying to use ChefSpec to test an implementation of Chef and Hashicorp Vault

Recipe

```
chef_gem 'vault' do
  compile_time true if Chef::Resource::ChefGem.instance_methods(false).include?(:compile_time)
end

require 'vault'

Vault.address = 'https://address:8200'
Vault.token = citadel['foo/bar']
Vault.auth_token.renew_self
```

Test

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

describe 'wrapper::default' do
  context 'role is foo' do
    let(:chef_run) do
      ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '14.04') do |node|
        node.default['role'] = 'foo'
        const_set(:Vault, Module.new)
      end.converge(described_recipe)
    end

    before(:each) do
      allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Recipe).to receive(:require).and_call_original
      allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Recipe).to receive(:require).with('vault').and_return(true)
      allow_any_instance_of(::Vault).to receive(:address).and_call_original
      allow_any_instance_of(::Vault).to receive(:address).with('https://localhost:8200').and_return(true)
    end

    it 'install vault gem' do
      expect(chef_run).to install_chef_gem('vault')
    end
  end
end
```

Error

```
Failure/Error: expect(Chef::Recipe::Vault).to receive(:address).and_call_original

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Vault
```

How do I stub the Vault variables?  This is Hashicorp Vault, not chef-vault.

Comment: did you get to resolve it? could you share your solution ?

Comment: this is what i ended up doing: stackoverflow.com/a/59981857/303114

Answer (score 2):

i got here and still couldnt figure it out
so i ended up moving my vault code into my own lib which i include in the recipe so i couldnt mock it out during ChefSpec run.

so i have under `my-cookbook/libraries/my_vault.rb` with this code:

```rb
require 'vault'

module MyVault
  module Helpers
    def get_vault_secret(secret)
      Vault.configure do |config|
        config.address = "#{node[:vault_url]}"
        config.token = "#{node[:vault_token]}"
      end
      Vault.logical.read(secret)
    end
  end
end
```

and in my recipe:

```rb
Chef::Recipe.send(:include, MyVault::Helpers)

creds = get_vault_secret("secret/jmx")
user = creds.data[:user]
password = creds.data[:password]


template "/etc/app/jmx.password" do
  source "jmx.password.erb"
  mode 0600
  owner "dev"
  group "dev"
  variables({
                :user => user,
                :password => password
            })
end
```

and my spec test:

```rb
require 'chefspec'
require 'chefspec/berkshelf'

describe 'app::metrics' do
  platform 'ubuntu', '14.04'

  before do
    response = Object.new
    allow(response).to receive_messages(:data => {
        :user => "benzi",
        :password => "benzi"
    })
    allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Recipe).to receive(:get_vault_secret).and_return(response)
  end


  describe 'adds jmx.access to app folder' do
    it { is_expected.to create_template('/etc/app/jmx.access')
        .with(
            user: 'dev',
            group: 'dev',
            mode: 0644
        ) }
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I responded to your email already, you want `allow_any_instance_of(::Vault)` and similar, and you may have to create the module (`const_set(:Vault, Module.new)`) if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: Updated my question, I added a constant and took out the Chef::Recipe, still getting uninitialized constant

Comment: Please see the second bit from above where you need to create the module using either `const_set` or `stub_const` before you can stub things on it.

Comment: could you share a full snippet? i'm facing a real challenge with making it work...

Comment: ChefSpec has changed a lot since 2016 so the answer here is no longer relevant. I rewrote the loader subsystem about 2 years ago to make stubbing more natural.

Comment: this is what i ended up doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59981857/303114